# Finding "gaps" in a list of numbers

Tags: haskell

I'm having trouble with going through a list. I made this code which gives me a list of numbers which are evenly divided by the sum of their digits. For example, consider the number 123: 123/6 = 20.5, so it will not be in the list. One the other hand 280 will be on the list, because 280/10 = 28.

```
let inaHelper x = (floor(x)`mod`10)+ (floor(x/10)`mod`10)+(floor(x/100)`mod`10)

let ina = [x | x <- [1..999] , x `mod` (inaHelper x) == 0  ]
```

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,18,20,21,24,27,30,36,40,42,45,48,50,54,60,63,70,72,80,81,84,90,100,102,108,110,111,112,114,117,120,126,132,133,135,140,144,150,152,153,156,162,171,180,190,192,195,198,200,201,204,207,209,210,216,220,222,224,225,228,230,234,240,243,247,252,261,264,266,270,280,285,288,300,306,308,312,315,320,322,324,330,333,336,342,351,360,364,370,372,375,378,392,396,399,400,402,405,407,408,410,414,420,423,432,440,441,444,448,450,460,465,468,476,480,481,486,500,504,506,510,511,512,513,516,518,522,531,540,550,552,555,558,576,588,592,594,600,603,605,612,621,624,629,630,640,644,645,648,660,666,684,690,700,702,704,711,715,720,730,732,735,736,738,756,770,774,777,780,782,792,800,801,803,804,810,820,825,828,832,840,846,864,870,874,880,882,888,900,902,910,912,915,918,935,936,954,960,966,972,990,999]`

But my problem now is: from the list above I only want the numbers that will not have a "neighbour" within a gap of 5 units. For example, the number 300 will be in the new list because it's neighbors (288 and 306) are not within the 5 unit gap.

I came up it this code:

```
let rare = [ x | x <- [ina]  , ((x-5) >= [ina-1]) && ((x+5) <= [ina+1])    ]
```

I'm a beginner, can someone help?

Comment: Don’t use floor, use div.

Answer (score 2):

An easy, though not very efficient, way would be to make a helper function which checks whether there is an element of a list within a certain range:

```
hasElemInRange :: (Int,Int) -> [Int] -> Bool
hasElemInRange (lo, hi) xs = -- left as exercise
```

(hint: you can use the [`any`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:any) function)

and then you can include it in your list comprehension:

```
let rare = [ x | x <- ina, hasElemInRange (x-5,x+5) ina ]
```

---

Another idiom that you might consider is zipping a list with its own tail.  So you can do:

```
ghci> let xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
ghci> zip3 xs (tail xs) (tail (tail xs))
[(1,2,3),(2,3,4),(3,4,5),(4,5,6),(5,6,7)]
```

Which will give you each element of the list with its "context", the element just before and after.  Maybe you can figure out how to use that for what you need.